# InvalidArchiveError in anaconda while installing scikit-image package

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, scikit-image

I have a new conda environment and I tried installing scikit-image package in this new conda environment by using this line of code.

```
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-image
```

but resulted in below error.

```
InvalidArchiveError('Error with archive C:\\Users\\wj96hq\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\openssl-1.1.1g-he774522_0.tar.bz2.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nCould not unlink')
```

It would be great if someone can help me with this?

Comment: I would first try `conda clean --all` and if this does not yet solve the issue, I'd manually locate and delete this file `C:\\Users\\wj96hq\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\openssl-1.1.1g-he774522_0.tar.bz2`